# Angular 2 http - get data from API

Tags: api, angular

I'm trying to get data in JSON format from this site https://api.chucknorris.io/ (random joke), but i get an error:ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. And "DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 11, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}"

This is routing.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RandomService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        console.log('working');

    }
    getRandomJokes() {
        return this.http.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

This is the component i'm trying to get data into

```
<div *ngFor="let joke of jokes">
<h3>{{joke.value}}</h3>
</div>

`,
providers: [RandomService]

})
export class PocetnaComponent  { 
jokes: Joke[];

constructor(private jokesService: RandomService){
this.jokesService.getRandomJokes().subscribe(jokes => {this.jokes = jokes});
}

}
interface Joke{
 id: number;
 value: string;
}
```

Comment: `getRandomJokes()` is not returning an array so jokes on you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not binding an array to the `*ngFor`, you have to make sure that `jokes` is actually an array and not a random joke object.

To solve it if it is an object you can just do `this.jokes = [jokes]`.

Comment: This is a fine solution, but why even set `jokes` in array? Why not just remove the *ngFor and just show the properties of the object?

Comment: @AJT_82 That's what I would do but it's not the question. Therefore it's not the answer :)

Comment: Well, in my opinion nowhere is mentioned that it needs to be an array. I think we should always guide to "a better way" if there is one. Think if the code would be more complicated and more costly and you know there is a better/faster/easier (etc) way, why not then suggest that? :) I would, and I do if I'm smart enough to figure out a better solution (rarely happens :P ).

Answer (score 1):

Since what you are receiving is not an array, but an object, therefore the error you are getting is because an object cannot be iterated. You might want to rethink the naming, since we are dealing with just one object, `joke` would be a more suitable name. But here, let's use `jokes`.

So you should do is remove the `*ngFor` completely and simply display the value with:

```
{{jokes?.value}}
```

Nothing else is needed :) Notice the safe navigation operator here, which safeguards null and undefined  values in property paths. Be prepared to use this a lot in the asynchronous world ;)

Here is more info about the safe navigation operator, from the **[official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator)**.

Answer (score 0):

The `url` you mention only provides a single value in an object, so you cannot iterate over it.

Maybe make multiple calls like this:

```
getRandomJokes(n = 10){
    return Promise.all(Array(n).fill(0)
            .map(() => this.http.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random').toPromise()
                                .then(res => res.json()));
}
```

and use with promise

```
this.jokesService.getRandomJokes().then(jokes => {this.jokes = jokes});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if it is an array and then go for ngFor or convert the jokes to array like let jokes = [jokes];

```
<div *ngIf = "jokes.length > 0" ; else check>
    <div *ngFor="let joke of jokes">
        <h3>{{joke.value}}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<ng-template #check>
    <p>print the value of the object </p>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be `jokes` isn't an array.

```
 <div *ngIf="Array.isArray(jokes)>
<div *ngFor="let joke of jokes"> 
<h3>{{joke.value}}</h3> 
</div>
```